# Python 3 find a string between two points

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, search

I've had this working fine in py2.7, but am having trouble getting it to now work in in py3 with the changes to regex

i just want the string "`voltaire`" returned from a file name

```
gpxFileName = '235235voltaire.gpx'
m=re.search('(?<=[0-9]).*?(?=.gpx)',gpxFileName)
print (m.group(1))
```

the above code successfully prunes off the .gpx fine, but the numbers stay in :(

i've been stuck on this for waaaaay too long, and its KILLING me. wot am i missing??

btw, i have also tried

```
m=re.search('(?<=[0-9])\w+',gpxFileName)
```

and

```
m=re.search('(?<=\d).*(?=.gpx)',gpxFileName)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [*capturing groups*](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#grouping):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '235235voltaire.gpx'
>>> re.search(r'\d+(\w+)\.gpx', s).group(1)
'voltaire'
```

Here we are extracting one or more alphanumeric characters right after one or more digits and right before the `.gpx` (dot has to be escaped since it has a *special meaning*).

Comment: you are an absolute legend! thanks. So i learn too, what do you mean by capturing ?

Comment: @user2206361 thanks, the italic font is just to put an emphasis.

Comment: OK i geddit that the dot has a special meaning but the (?=.gpx) was the part that was successfully working - it was the numbers that were not being pruned out. Oh and can you explain ....i guess the '+'s mean any length of.. right?

Comment: @user2206361 `+` means "one or more". If you want to use look behind and ahead checks, here is a sample expression that would extract `voltaire`: `(?<=\d{6})(\w+)(?=\.gpx)`.

Comment: awesome. clear and informative. thanks and happy holidays!